# React Native Expo - Exception when putting TextInput on Modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When I put a `<Text>` element on a modal it works fine.

When I replace this with a `<TextInput>` I get an error message appear **behind** the Modal.

I am using expo CLI 3.18.2 and testing on an android Google Pixel 3a.

I have created the simplest possible example to illustrate the problem, any help would be much appreciated.

This works and "Hello" is displayed on the screen in a Modal:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';

const MyModal = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyModal;
```

This breaks:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';

const MyModal = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => console.log(text)}
        value='Hello' // It does not matter what I put here, even if it is a state oject
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyModal;
```

Here is the code to launch the Modal:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Modal, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import MyModal from './CreateModalBroken';


const App = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <MyModal />
      </Modal>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 200 }}>
        <View style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', margin: 10, borderRadius: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue', paddingTop: 10, paddingBottom: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Show Modal</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is a screenshot of the error (apologies for the giant size). This actually appears behind the modal and the whole application stops working, though I was able to get a screenshot of just the error without the modal in the way after refreshing a few times.

Thanks for your help.

[image]